# Python: how to convert timestamp to date in a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dataframe like the following

```
print (df)
            T
0  1573119509
1  1573119512
2  1573119517
3  1573119520
```

I would like to convert the column `T` to a date. This is what I am doing:

```
df['Td'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T']).apply(lambda x: x.date())
```

but it returns:

```
print (df)
            T           Td
0  1573119509   1970-01-01
1  1573119512   1970-01-01
2  1573119517   1970-01-01
3  1573119520   1970-01-01
```

Answer (score 4):

Use parameter `unit='s'` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
df['Td'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T'], unit='s').dt.date
print (df)
            T          Td
0  1573119509  2019-11-07
1  1573119512  2019-11-07
2  1573119517  2019-11-07
3  1573119520  2019-11-07
```

Comment: I would like display also seconds and milliseconds. This i what I am doing `df['Td'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T'], unit='s').dt.date`. How can I show seconds and milliseconds for plotting all the different points?

Comment: @emax I think you can use `df['Td'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T'], unit='s')` only, becase converting to dates remove times, also seconds and milliseconds. If need better precision only is necessary not rounding like in my previous answer and use  `df['Td'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T'], unit='ms')`  change `s` to `ms`